# Simple program using uniform initialization to construct an object fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, uniform-initialization

Consider the following program:

```
struct X
{
    X(int, int) { }
    X(X&&) { }
};

int main()
{
    X x( {0, 1} ); // Doesn't compile on ICC 13.0.1, compiles on
                   // Clang 3.2, GCC 4.7.2, and GCC 4.8.0 beta.
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8.0, and Clang 3.2, this program does the following (*):

1. Constructs a temporary of type `X` passing values `0` and `1` to the constructor, then;
2. Move-constructs `X` from that temporary.

With ICC 13.0.1, instead, it doesn't compile.

**QUESTION #1: Who is right?**

(*) *Actually, the creation of the temporary and the call to the move constructor are elided, but compiling with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option and adding some printouts to the constructors reveals that this is what is going on.*

---

Now consider the following, slight variation of the above program, where *uniform initialization* is used to direct-initialize `x`:

```
int main()
{
    X x{ {0, 1} }; // ERROR! Doesn't compile.
//     ^........^
}
```

I would not expect the use of braces instead of parentheses to change anything here, but it somehow does: this program doesn't compile on *any* of the compilers I've tested it on (Clang 3.2, GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8.0 beta, and ICC 13.0.1).

**QUESTION #2: Why?**

Comment: I'm curious as to what errors you get with the second one.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Check it out [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/10CpDi$73), you can choose the compiler.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that this isn't how SO works. If it's pertinent, you put it in the question, not link to some live-workspace page.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I just did not think it is pertinent. It seems to me that this example is simple enough to allow anybody to reason on it without depending on a compiler, but if someone is curious about what concrete message did any of those 4 compilers emit, he can try it. Copy-pasting a 10 lines program is quick enough, but since you asked, I made that even easier and provided a link.

Comment: What's wrong with good old plain `X x{0,1};`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a bug in all the compilers. §8.5.4/3 says,

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> — If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>   value-initialized.
>
> — Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
> — Otherwise, if T is a specialization of std::initializer_list, an initializer_list object is constructed as described below and used to initialize the object …
>
> **— Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.**
>
> — Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary.
>
> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object or reference is initialized from that element; if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed.
>
> …

There are *quite a few* cases. Note that you're actually list-initializing an prvalue temporary object bound to the rvalue reference.

As for GCC, I think it's trying to apply the last item mentioned above, for a single-element initializer list. If I change the constructor signature to `X(X&&, int = 3)`, then the initializer `{ {0, 1} }` fails but `{ {0, 1}, 3 }` succeeds. The single item should succeed because because the element is a braced-init-list, and I believe that case is supposed to allow extra enclosing braces, analogous to parens. But the failure is similar to other shortcomings of GCC with brace elision.

My high-level impression is that the problems arise when the compiler tries to treat the list as an object with a type, which it's not. It's hard to convert that back to something like a parenthesized argument list.

Looking more specifically at the error messages (thanks for the LWS link),

- ICC insists it expects an expression. This is wrong because according to the basic grammar, braced-init-lists can enclose other braced-init-lists, not only expressions.
- Clang says *"candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'X'"* but it works if the conversion is explicit, using `X x{ X{0, 0 } };`. That doesn't make sense. It's not a conversion, because a list doesn't have a type to convert from. It's list-initialization.
- GCC says *"no known conversion for argument 1 from '' to 'X&&'"* suggesting it didn't even get to the point of defining a temporary to bind to the reference. As with Clang it seems to be attempting spurious conversion, and specifying `X{0,0}` fixes it.

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes. I don't have ICC and I think the first example is correct. (Indeed, I think the second one is too.)

Comment: So you think both programs should compile? (btw, [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/10CpDi$87) you can select ICC)

Comment: @AndyProwl Yep. The trick I mentioned also satisfies Clang but not ICC, which expects an expression. It *certainly* has no reason to expect an expression there. Braced-init-lists may contain expressions, or other braced-init-lists.

Comment: I was reading the same paragraph you quoted, and I also got to the item in bold, and there I stopped. Are you implying GCC didn't, and skipped right to the last item?

Comment: @Andy Yep. And Clang correctly executed the next item (bind a reference), but still skipped #3 on the second pass.

Comment: Ok, +1 for now. Tomorrow I'll read through it again with a fresher mind ;-)

Comment: OK, indeed this MUST be a bug. There is no reason why [this one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1AzAfL$2) should work and [this one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/31UWw9$0) should not.